# Not able to resolve dependencies for implementation of SAX based event API using poi

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, xlsx, sax

I am trying to implement a SAX based event API for reading large xlsx files using Apache POI.
I am trying to set-up the example in my eclipse workspace present at below location:

[XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java)

But I am not able to resolve below dependencies in my workspace:

> org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.SAXHelper
>       org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStrings
>       org.apache.poi.xssf.model.Styles

I have got below jars in classpath:

> poi-3.17.jar
>       poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
>       poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
>       poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
>       xmlbeans.jar
>       poi-excelant-3.17.jar
>       ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar
>       dom4j-1.6.1.jar
>       ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar

Could somebody please guide me,what all dependencies are needed for SAX
based implementation of poi?

Comment: Check your classpath - it looks like you have older POI jars on there too by mistake

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-shared-strings-sample has a gradle build that runs the XLSX2CSV sample.